# Ruby's ruport NoMethodError (undefined method `Table' for main:Object)

Tags: ruby, ruport

The Ruport gem is failing to find the Table method. Using the example at https://ruport.github.io/examples.html we see the issue. I'm not sure if this is a bug or an issue with my configuration.

```
$ cat foo.csv
name,login time,machine
Gregory,10:00,bittle
Joe,11:45,soda
Jim,9:00,kitten
Joe,12:15,soda
Gregory,5:00,kitten
Joe,12:45,bittle

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin18]

$ gem list ruport

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

ruport (1.7.1)

$ irb
>> require 'ruport'
=> true
>> t = Table("foo.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/davidhooey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/davidhooey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/davidhooey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.3/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):2
NoMethodError (undefined method `Table' for main:Object)
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this Gem is assuming that you are working in the context of Rails's `ActiveRecord` class and thus it `require "ruport/acts_as_reportable"` [here](https://github.com/ruport/ruport/blob/master/lib/ruport.rb#L105)

which will make you code work perfectly if it's written inside an ActiveRecord child class but not in IRB. You can still use the class `table`/library by using its full name `Ruport::Data::Table` instead of just `Table`.

So your code will become:

```
>> require 'ruport'
=> true
>> t = Ruport::Data::Table("foo.csv")
```